# Why when i click button for a certain row, but keeps on passing value of first row

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I would like to pass value from a chosen row to the controller action so that the value will be passed as a session. The passing of value to controller is working, but the thing is, when i press a certain row's button, it keeps on passing the value of the first row. How can i make so that each row's button passes the row's values respectively?

```
<form Class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="@Url.Action("Lookup", "home")" method="post">
    @For Each item In Model.Details
        @<tr Class="even gradeC">
            <td><input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="@item.id">@item.id</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value="@item.name">@item.name</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><Button type="submit" Class="btn btn-default" name="btnSelect" value="@item.id">Select</Button></td>
        </tr>
     Next
 </form>
```

This is in the controller:

```
Function Lookup(btnSelect As String, id As String, name As String) As ActionResult
  If btnSelect.Equals(id) Then
     Session("id") = id
     Session("name") = name
  End If
End Function
```

| 1 | Ana   | Select |

| 2 | Bella | Select |

When i press button at row 2, it passes value '1' and 'Ana'. I already tried putting the value of id to each button to identify the buttons, but it seemed like it still passes the values of first row, all the times.

When i looked at the values during breakpoint, the value of button is correct - '2' but the value for 'id' and 'name' is always '1' and 'Ana'. What am i missing here? Could anyone help me please?

Comment: The code you have shown will not do that so I assume you must have some javascript involved. (and `FormMethod.Post` is `Url.Action()` makes no sense so remove that). And that code is clearly inside a loop which means your generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes)

Comment: @StephenMuecke alright, thanks. but is there any other way to pass the values without involving javascript? i've skipped a few things there, i've updated my question

Comment: You don't need any javascript for this. But your code makes no sense. All you have are hidden inputs which cannot be edited. What are you trying to achieve with this (and the reason it does not work is because you have multiple inputs with the same name inside a single form and the `DefaultModelBinder` only binds the first value and ignores the rest)

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry but i don't quite understand. which inputs have the same name? I'm trying to pass all values: id and name of the respective row with the click of that row's 'select' button. and i tried to put the value of the button the same as id, so that i can ensure that only that chosen row's values will be sent to the controller.

Comment: You have a loop (your `@For Each` in side a single `<form>` element and your creating multiple hidden inputs with `name="id" and `name="name"` (and worse, you have duplicate `id` attributes). And what is the point of posting back a value for the button - its value is always `@item.id` so your `If btnSelect.Equals(id) Then` ALWAYS returns `True` (making it pointless). Give me 10 min and I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loop inside your `<form>` element which is generating duplicate `name` attributes for your hidden inputs in each iteration (you have multiple inputs with `name="id"` and `name="name"`).

When you click a submit button, all the name/value pairs of all inputs are posted and the `DefaultModelBinder` only reads the first one with a matching name and ignores the rest (unless you parameters were `IEnumerable(Of String)` in which case the parameters would contain an collection of all values).

You code is also generating invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes.

You can solve this by generating a new `<form>` in each iteration

```
@For Each item In Model.Details
    @<tr Class="even gradeC">
        <td>@item.id</td>
        <td>@item.id</td>
        <td>
            <form Class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="@Url.Action("Lookup", "home")" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.id" />
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="@item.name" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Select</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
Next
```

Note that the `id` attributes have been removed, and the `name` and `value` attribute from the button has been removed. There is no point in passing back a value for the button since its value is `@item.id` and your `If btnSelect.Equals(id) Then` line of code always returns `True` making it pointless. You controller method should be just

```
Function Lookup(id As String, name As String) As ActionResult
    Session("id") = id
    Session("name") = name
    ....
End Function
```

Side note: You do not really need the hidden inputs, and you can simply add the values as route or query sting values in the forms `action` attribute

```
action="@Url.Action("Lookup", "home", New With { .id = item.id, .name = item.name })"
```

Comment: Can't. 1 error: 1) "Element 'form' cannot be nested inside element 'tbody'".

Comment: For the first - cant be sure (like most people I have not used VB for 15 years) but I'm sure you can work out the correct syntax. And you did not show any `tbody` in your question, but just put the form inside a `<td>` element - give me 5 min and I'll update that bit

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was trying to keep it simple i thought it didn't matter much.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great help! U saved my day! Bundling up all the needed variables in url.action is really neat and saves space! :D

Comment: Just wondering, because when i tried to change the value of the id in the URL, the URL and the id passed in the method changed. This will mess up the other process and cause data inconsistency. Then i changed the displaying function from inside GET to POST. Now when i changed the URL value, it will instead display blank value because i put nothing in the GET method. But then i had to redo the lookup process because the id value is now lost. Its a bit tedious if this happens. Is there any way so that user can't change the value of URL and messes up the whole process?

Comment: @Nurul, Sorry, I'm not sure what your asking (and what you saying does not makes sense so I assume there is something wrong with your code). You needs to ask a new question explaining the issue and showing the code your using

Comment: Sorry i made you confused. By URL, i meant address bar. I used the wrong term. I made a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846421/how-do-i-hide-my-variable-name-from-address-url-bar), could you have a look at it please?

Comment: Sorry i had to ask once more. Previously when i pass multiple values using New With { .id = item.id, .name = item.name }, it worked. But now when i tried the same thing in another form, only id is passed. I realized this happens probably because i put method as 'get'. Can't i pass multiple values in get method?

Comment: Yes of course. But I do not know how your passing them, or what the parameters of the method are.

Comment: I've edited my question. Could you have a look at it please?

Comment: First of all, I have rolled back your edit (this site is one question and a time and if you have a new issue, then you need to as ask a new question). But the code you showed worked fine so if your not getting the values, then I assume that they are `null` in the first place. Suggest you look at at the html your generating in the `<form>` tag t see if the `action` attribute contains the correct url

Comment: I tried changing the form method to 'post' and both values are passed just fine. it just didn't work when it is set to 'get'.

Comment: There is no difference (assuming you have removed any `[HttpPost]` attribute you may have had previously). Are you hitting the method (and the parameters are just `null`) or is it not hitting the method at all

Comment: When i looked at the sourcecode of the page, the table rows contains both values. I put a breakpoint at the form but it somehow skipped the breakpoint. But at the controller breakpoint, i saw that id is passed, but visitId has no value. It didn't give a null error there, only at the query in viewmodel method because i queried for both values with 'AND' filter.

Comment: I cannot guess what the code your actually using is, so please ask another question with the relevant code and an explanation of what you expect to happen and what actually happens.