# How do i hide my variable name from address URL bar?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm passing value to-and-fro controller and view in MVC. The thing is, if possible i wanted to hide my variable name from the URL/address bar from users seeing it. I've tried route config and did as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Default2",
        url:="{controller}/{action}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "home", .action = "Lookup"}
)
routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Default",
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "home", .action = "Lookup", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
)
```

I've also tried below, i know it looks quite absurd but i tried anyway.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Default2",
        url:="{controller}/{action}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "home", .action = "Lookup"}
)
routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Default",
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id&name}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "home", .action = "Lookup", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
)
```

I tried both. Instead of hiding the variable i passed as parameters in the controller, it hides my controller and action, and just showed the variable name.

```
http://localhost:11111/?id=P59068&name=Nurul
```

I was hoping it would display like this instead:

```
http://localhost:11111/home/Lookup/P59068&Nurul
```

I've seen several websites showing like above but i don't know if what i'm doing is the right thing to achieve what i want. What am i doing wrong? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Probably is _Url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}"_

Comment: You cannot get `/home/Lookup/P59068&Nurul` but you can get `/home/Lookup/P59068/Nurul` - is that acceptable?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thats good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to generate `/home/Lookup/P59068&Nurul`, but you can generate `/home/Lookup/P59068/Nurul` by changing your `Default2` route to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name:="Default2",
    url:="home/lookup/{id}/{name}",
    defaults:=New With {.controller = "home", .action = "Lookup"}
)
```

This needs to before the `Default` route or any other matching routes.

The additional of the last 2 segments in the `url` property (`/{id}/{name}`) means that those values are added as route values rather than query string parameters

Note also you could generate `/Lookup/P59068/Nurul` (without the "home" prefix using `url:="lookup/{id}/{name}"`)

Comment: I've tried but it still shows my variable names in the address bar

Comment: Then you have not put that route first - If you were to use `@Html.ActionLink("xxx", "Lookup", "Home", new { id = "P59068", name = "Nurul" }, null)` in a view, it will generate `/home.lookup/P59068/Nurul`

Comment: Where do i put that? In every view? Where exactly? At the button that passes those values to the controller?

Comment: You have not indicated how your passing the values to your controller (I just gave you an example). Is this related to you [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820076/why-when-i-click-button-for-a-certain-row-but-keeps-on-passing-value-of-first-r) - in which case its `action="@Url.Action("Lookup", "home", New With { .id = item.id, .name = item.name })"` in the `<form>` tag (and delete the hidden inputs)

Comment: Yes its related. Ok that solves everything! Thanks a lot! Never thought the hidden input is the cause here

Comment: A form with `FormMethod.Get` sends back the values of its form controls as query string parameters (your browser knows nothing about your route definitions)

Comment: So in other words, i should avoid passing confidential data or any data to httpget right? Next, i'm thinking of passing the selected user to the next and subsequent pages, should i use tempdata and then pass that tempdata to httppost? I'm thinking of using session but i've read session is not that safe.

Comment: For a start `TempData` is `Session`. Its not clear what your trying to do - what data is confidential? If its user entered information, then your POST a form. If its data that exists on the server (e.g. in a database), it should never be sent from a view to the server (and it does not need to be because the server already knows it)

Comment: Say i have a patient lookup page where a patient is selected. Then from the chosen user, that user's data is passed from current controller(Lookup) to another controller(Assign doctor to patient). I'm using a viewmodel so i'm passing data to and from that viewmodel. And the basic user information is displayed on the top part of the screen for the subsequent pages after the lookup page. What is the best way to send it controller-controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133965/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nurul).